# Electron + MSAL OAuth 2.0 redirection issue due to form-action during authentication

Tags: electron, azure-ad-msal, content-security-policy, pkce

Packages:

- `@azure/msal-node: ^2.6.4`
- `electron: 21.1.1`

I am trying to configure an authorization code flow with PKCE. For that - I am spawning a new window in electron and go through the MS login flow. I have 2FA enabled so when I get to the last step and enter the code in the MS Authentication app on my phone I see in the debug console of the electron app the following error:

> Refused to send form data to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/SAS/ProcessAuth' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self' http https ws wss https: *.microsoftonline.com".

I looked through the [CSP: form-action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/form-action) mozilla documentation and as you can see above - updated my CSP policy to include everything I could think of to make this work, however, to no avail.

Here is my full current CSP policy

```
const contentSecurityPolicy = [
  "default-src 'self' https:",
  "script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https:",
  "connect-src * 'unsafe-inline' https:",
  "font-src 'self' https:",
  "form-action 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ws: wss: http: https: data: mediaStream: blob: filesystem: *.microsoftonline.com",
  "img-src 'self' blob: data: https:",
  "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https:"
];
```

There is also some warning on the mozilla's documentation page about `form-action` and browser support for re-directs, but I admin I don't fully understand it. Surely there must be a way to make it work in electron.

Comment: My best guess would be that a redirect occurs, but given all the schemes present, there should be no reason to block. Check the network tab in dev tools for what happens when you post.